# How to add new value inside a cell of Datatable Plugin?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to develop a 'Student Attendance entry form' using CodeIgniter & MySql. To register the attendance, I'm using hyperlinks present inside a datatable to mark as 'Present' or 'Absent'.
[image]
As you can see in the above image, that when either 'Is Present' or 'Is Absent' is clicked, **

> I want to update the cell(column-4) with values like 'P' or 'A'.

**

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#" data-value="a-p" class="btn-p"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Is Present</a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#" data-value="a-a" class="btn-a"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Is Absent</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var tbl = $('#student_table').DataTable();
    $(document).on('click', 'a.btn-p', function (e) {
        var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
        var a_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var access_for = $(this).data("value");
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            var rowIndex = tbl.cell(this).index().row;
            tbl.cell(rowIndex,4).data("new val");
            alert('Testing Testing!');
        }           
    });
```

My code is not producing the desired result. Help wanted with some code, please. My datatable plugin version is (DataTables 1.10.6)(datatables.net)

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()

Comment: _"My code is not producing the desired result"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_